# how can i read a collection of objects saved in an xml in a spring app

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have set of static data in xml like

```
<books>
  <book id="isbn-1"> 
    <name>name1</name>
    <author>athorname</author>
  </book>
  <book id="isbn-2"> 
    <name>name1</name>
    <author>athorname</author>
  </book>
</books>
```

I would like to read them and load them in Book model object just like they were in DB.

Given a isbn I would like to parse this xml and load the corresponding object etc.

One way I can achieve this is load it as list in memory. 
The other way is maybe store each book in different xml with isbn as xml name and load it.

one - doesnt work if the list is huge.
two - creates lots of files and difficult to manage.

Is there any other way I can achieve this using spring-framework or any other java library?

Comment: Is memory really an issue? I'd benchmark this by looping through the same 10 records X N times to see how memory usage increases with number of records. You may find that you'd (totally guessing) need > 10 million records to run out of memory on a server running under 2GB of memory. Alternatively I'd look at using the embedded SQL database "H2" to store the records. Dead easy to setup and get going with Hibernate or JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB + StAX
This problem/question  is orthogonal to spring